# Getting java.io.EOFException: End of input at line 1 column 1 while uploading an Image to server using retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2, multipartform-data

I'm trying to upload an image to the server using retrofit 2 multipart request and Gson parser
I tested the api by postman and its working fine but in android I'm getting the mentioned exception

Here's my code

this is retrofit dependency

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.5.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.5.0'
```

Api Client

```
public class ApiClient {

public static final String BASE_URL = "http://www.AAbd.com/api/";
private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


public static Retrofit getClient() {
    if (retrofit==null) {

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                .create();

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
```

}

Api Interface

```
@POST("edit/Image")
@Multipart
Call<AuthModel> addImage (@Part("api_token") RequestBody api_token,
                                @Part("image") MultipartBody.Part image);
```

Model

```
@Expose
@SerializedName("api_token_status")
private String api_token_status;
@Expose
@SerializedName("status")
private String status;
@Expose
@SerializedName("message")
private String message;


public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public String getApi_token_status() {
    return api_token_status;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}
```

Calling the request

```
public void addImageRequest (Bitmap image) {
    try {
        File f = new File(getCacheDir(), "offf");
        f.createNewFile();
        Bitmap bitmap = image;
        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 0 /*ignored for PNG*/, bos);
        byte[] bitmapdata = bos.toByteArray();
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
        fos.write(bitmapdata);
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();


        RequestBody reqFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/*"), f);
        MultipartBody.Part body = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("image", f.getName(), reqFile);
        RequestBody tokenRequest = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), token2);
        apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        Call<AuthModel> call = apiInterface.addImage(tokenRequest, body);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<AuthModel>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<AuthModel> call, Response<AuthModel> response) {
                AuthModel result = response.body();
                if(result != null) {
                    String status = result.getStatus();
                    String msg = result.getMessage();
                    if(status.equals("true")) {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.e("errorIs", msg);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Log.e("errorIs", msg);
                    }
                } else {
                    try {
                        //Toast.makeText(context, response.errorBody().string() , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<AuthModel> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, t.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });

    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I checked all the previous questions regarding this issue but I didn't find a possible solution for my case. Please help and thanks in advance

Comment: Are you able to get the image at least and get the file of it?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS yes this is for sure

Comment: Does your model contains set and get or just get?

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS get only

Comment: Please, add the set and let me know if it works.

Comment: EOFexception occures when socked is disconnected.it might be happened by firewall.check security issues.

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS I just added setters and tried but still not working

Comment: @Mr.AF please tell me more details about firewall configuration that may cause such kind of issues

Comment: Firewall configuration is somehow trouble.i recommend you test your application in low security .turn off firewall.and also in http requests in large data you should add header keep alive connection.

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS Can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783444/why-does-multipart-pdf-is-not-able-to-upload-in-api-using-retrofit-2-in-android?noredirect=1#comment111031344_62783444

Comment: @Mr.AF Can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783444/why-does-multipart-pdf-is-not-able-to-upload-in-api-using-retrofit-2-in-android?noredirect=1#comment111031344_62783444

Comment: @Michael Can you help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62783444/why-does-multipart-pdf-is-not-able-to-upload-in-api-using-retrofit-2-in-android?noredirect=1#comment111031344_62783444